# how to pass dbcontext as a parameter in generic data access layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics, dbcontext

I have a generic data access layer implemented by an interface that will be used by different modules with different DB context.

Here is the code:

```
 public class GenericDataRepository<T> : IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class
{



    public virtual IList<T> Get(Func<T, bool> filter, int page, int pageSize, string[] includePaths = null, params SortExpression<T>[] sortExpressions)
    {
        List<T> list;
        using (var context = new _DbContext())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();
            if (includePaths != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < includePaths.Count(); i++)
                {
                    dbQuery = dbQuery.Include(includePaths[i]);
                }
            }
            if (filter != null)
            {
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(filter).AsQueryable();
            }
            IOrderedEnumerable<T> orderedQuery = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < sortExpressions.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    if (sortExpressions[i].SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        orderedQuery = dbQuery.OrderBy(sortExpressions[i].SortBy);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        orderedQuery = dbQuery.OrderByDescending(sortExpressions[i].SortBy);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (sortExpressions[i].SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(sortExpressions[i].SortBy);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(sortExpressions[i].SortBy);
                    }
                }
                dbQuery = orderedQuery.AsQueryable();
            }
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Skip(((int)page - 1) * (int)pageSize);
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Take((int)pageSize);

            list = dbQuery
           .ToList<T>();

        }
        return list;

    }
}
```

In this GenericDataRepository layer, I don't have DB context class. I want this GenericDataRepository to accept DB context as an incoming parameter from different calling module to perform operations written in Getting method.

You can see I use
`using (var context = new _DbContext())`
 In getting method. I don't know how to write GenericDataRepository to accomplish this goal.

this is my interface

```
 public interface IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class
{


    IList<T> Get(Func<T, bool> filter, int page, int pageSize, string[] includePaths = null, params SortExpression<T>[] sortExpressions);
       }
 }
```

Comment: It's unusual for a repository to use a context per method. Even context per repository is. Usually, repositories work with a context from an encompassing Unit of Work. It depends on the bigger picture how you're going to inject contexts. Your question is too narrow to be answerable.

Comment: i am using generic repository , the task of that repository to CRUD opetation  for different dbcontext . i have differenet modules in solution every module have saperate db context

Comment: Just add a `DbContext` parameter to the Get method.

Comment: @BrandonKramer Error .......

Comment: @FrazZaki Please include error information. It is hard to answer issues without seeing the actual error.

Comment: @FrazZaki Please share the interface code as well. Can you change the interface?

Comment: @ArnabChakraborty  Interface added

Comment: @ArnabChakraborty actually its fixed , i mean my generic repository is out of error but i am struck where from i want to call this repository , i couldnt pass db context from there ..

Comment: You will have to bubble up the dependency to the layer which has access to dbcontext.

Comment: If you hang on to this design your so-called repository isn't a repository at all, but more like service class.

Comment: @GertArnold Please share if you have a better design.

Comment: @ArnabChakraborty my problem solved brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dependency inversion principle. Inject a DbContext factory in your class constructor. Create and dispose of the context using the factory instead of accessing the context directly.

Here is a rough sample:

```
public class GenericDataRepository<T> : IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<DbContext> _contextFactory;
    public GenericDataRepository(Func<DbContext> contextFactory) 
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public virtual IList<T> Get(Func<T, bool> filter, int page, int pageSize, string[] includePaths = null, params SortExpression<T>[] sortExpressions)
    {
        List<T> list;
        using (var context = contextFactory())
        {
             //...
        }
     }
}
```

Assuming that the layer which is using the generic data repository has access to Dbcontext, they can now instantiate the repository in the following manner:

```
var repository = new GenericDataRepository<SomeType>(DbContextfactory);
public void DbcontextFactory() 
{
    return new _DbContext();
}
```

Comment: now my context.Set<T> said : contextFactory does not contain method of set

Comment: its fixed but cannot call this repository from other layer

Comment: fixed by this code : public abstract class GenericDataRepository<T,C> : IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class where C : DbContext, new()
    {